# How bad is it to use hyphens in a conan package name?

Tags: naming-conventions, hyphenation, package-management, conan-2

Suppose I have a librari named `foo-bar`, and I've written a `conanfile.py` for it. When running `conan create` for it, I get the warning:

```
WARN: Name containing special chars is discouraged 'foo-bar'
```

right away.

My question: How strongly is this discouraged? How bad is it - if at all - to have a Conan package name with hyphens/minus chars?

---

PS - In case it matters, I'm using Conan 2.0.13 and am hoping to get my package onto the Conan Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: There's a risk of conflicts when exporting packages whose names only vary in the special characters `+`/`-`/`_`. For example `foo+bar`, `foo-bar`, and `foo_bar`.

---

Looking at the [source where that warning is emitted](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/blob/02d0b7b6cb7697cd3b759a4a76aa11ac7f6283a0/conans/model/recipe_ref.py#L155), there's a comment that provides a bit of context:

```py
# Warn if they use .+- in the name/user/channel, as it can be problematic for generators
pattern = re.compile(r'[.+-]')
if pattern.search(self.name):
    ConanOutput().warning(f"Name containing special chars is discouraged '{self.name}'")
```

This check was added in PR [#12053](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/pull/12053) (issue [#11857](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/11857)), which was a response to PR [#11826](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/pull/11826) (issue [#11822](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/11822)). The root issue was that `+`s and `-`s in package names would both become normalized to `_` in some contexts, which could create ambiguity if two package names differed only in their use of `+`/`-`/`_`.

How bad using a `-` is depends on whether you think there's a risk of conflicts from exporting two packages that vary only in `+`/`-`/`_`.

I do not see any references about using `-`s being officially deprecated. The [tutorial in the docs](https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/creating_packages/create_your_first_package.html) still states that `-`s are valid in package names:

> `name`: a string, with a minimum of 2 and a maximum of 100 lowercase characters that defines the package name. It should start with alphanumeric or underscore and can contain alphanumeric, underscore, `+`, `.`, **`-` characters**.

Comment: So, "tldr: The only possible danger is a conflict with `foo_bar`." ?

Comment: @einpoklum Or with `foo+bar`. But yes, that's my reading of the issue